# How To Authenticate With Keys In ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I was able to authenticate with cookies in `ActionCable` using `cookies.signed[:user_id]` but I can't figure out how to do it using keys. For example, sending an `Authorization` header when establishing a connection.

The only variable that is accessible in the `ApplicationCable::Connection` class is `cookies`. The other variables (`params` and `headers`) are not available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to authenticate by sending authentication keys when subscribing to a channel. If keys are invalid, it calls `connection.send(:reject_unauthorized_connection)` in the channel.